# How can I populate a UIViewController after it's loaded?

Tags: iphone

I'd like my UIViewController to appear on the screen with a "Loading..." UILabel in the center and then, once that's been displayed, start loading data to display.

How can I achieve this?  I tried loading it in viewDidAppear:, but at this point the view has still not been displayed on the screen, so the app appears unresponsive to users.  If I try setting a short timer (0.0001 seconds) so that the view will be displayed and then the data loading method gets called in the run loop after that, for some reason the time it takes from opening the view controller to seeing content is about three times as long as it was without the timer.  In this case, the Loading... text appears, but the user has to wait way too long.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Better do this in a thread from `viewDidLoad` and call your method in a thread, before calling the thread show your label and when the data is loaded through the thread hide the label.

you can do it like this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self showLabel];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

**Update**

```
- (void) loadData:(id)object{  
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
   //Network Operations
   //...  
   //...  
   //...  
   //...  
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadView:) withObject:arg waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];  
   [pool release];  
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: be sure to put the seperate thread in an autorelease pool or you will get memory leaks

Comment: Cocoa is not thread-safe, so this will only work if the `loadData:` method shunts all GUI operations onto the main thread.

Comment: @Bill I thought that was but obvious. Updated the answer by the way.

Comment: I've voted this back up because whilst it's not the complete answer, the general idea is the best. As suggested an auto-release pool and running the return selector on the main thread is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

if I have not misunderstand your purpose, I think that you just want sow a 'loading' status to user, right ? if so , I suggest that you may use a simple ViewController to show the label 'Loading...' and then create the MainViw or next view which you want show to user in the end, when it was done, hide the first view show the MainView on screen...